# What is the format of git p4.largeFileExtensions for multiple extensions?

Tags: git, perforce

What is the correct format for this config?

My team is transitioning from P4 to git with LFS and I want to maintain commit history when we do so, so preconfiguring the extensions prior to checking out all the commits is important.

I've tried:

```
largeFileExtensions = foo,bar,baz
```

and

```
largeFileExtensions = foo bar baz
```

and

```
largeFileExtensions = foo
largeFileExtensions = bar
largeFileExtensions = baz
```

and

```
largeFileExtensions[] = foo
largeFileExtensions[] = bar
largeFileExtensions[] = baz
```

Answer (score 1):

In general, the Git `.git/config` syntax for multi-valued options is:

```
[section]
    key = value
    key = value
    key = value
```

git-p4 appears to use the same format too – it runs `git config --get-all largeFileExtensions` and expects to receive one extension per line.